# Compile PHP 7.1.5 with PCRE 8.40

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, make, pcre

I tried to compile a PHP 7.1.5 with PCRE 8.40 on a legacy Ubuntu 12.04.05 LTS:

1, I compiled PCRE 8.40 from source to /usr/local/pcre.

2, configure PHP:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --with-pcre-regex=/usr/local/pcre --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local/pcre
```

No error.

3, compile PHP:

```
make
```

Error:

```
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `zm_globals_dtor_pcre':
/root/php-7.1.5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:139: undefined reference to `pcre_jit_stack_free'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `php_free_pcre_cache':
/root/php-7.1.5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:113: undefined reference to `pcre_free_study'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `zm_activate_pcre':
/root/php-7.1.5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:223: undefined reference to `pcre_jit_stack_alloc'
ext/pcre/.libs/php_pcre.o: In function `pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache':
/root/php-7.1.5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:525: undefined reference to `pcre_assign_jit_stack'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I tried an experiment:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --disable-all --with-pcre-regex=/usr/local/pcre --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local/pcre
```

(--disable-all: Disable all extensions which are enabled by default.)

```
make
```

No error, build complete.

```
$/usr/local/php7/bin/php -i | grep "PCRE Library Version"
PCRE Library Version => 8.40 2017-01-11
```

**Why not working when I try without --disable-all option?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Compile PCRE with `--enable-jit` solved this for me.